# GDB pretty print custom type containing double array

Tags: python, c++, gdb

Trying to write a Python extension to GDB which is able to pretty print the following C++ class:

```
class Vector {
  double* myElements;
  unsigned int length;
}
```

where the pretty print output should be eg. `{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}` where the array `myElements` is of length `length`.

In gdb, I can simply do `*myVec.myElements@myVec.length` however I want to create the Python pretty print which does the equivalent.

My current attempt looks as follows:

```
class VectorPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        length = self.val['length']
        elmts = self.val['myElements']
        result = []
        for i in range(0, length):
            result.append(elmts[i])

        return str(result)


class FailPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        return "Value: " + str(self.val.type)

def lookup_type(val):
    if(str(val.type) == 'Vector'):
        return VectorPrinter(val)
    return FailPrinter(val)

gdb.pretty_printers.append(lookup_type)
```

However this just outputs:

```
$1 = [<gdb.Value object at 0x000000000367d470>, <gdb.Value object at 0x000000000367d4b0>, ...,
 <gdb.Value object at 0x000000000367d8f0>, <gdb.Value object at 0x000000000367d930>]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your type is some "kind of array" it is better to keep the `to_string` method simple (without handling the elements) and have
 a `children` method that returns a generator that retrieves the elements, as well as a `display_hint` method. This `display_hint` method must return the string "array" to indicate that gdb should use the `children` method to get the elements.

The `to_string` method can be as simple as just returning a simple string such as "vector", but I find useful to include the size of the vector.

I have created the following pretty-printer for your class

```py
class VectorPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.length = int(val['length'])
        self.mem = self.val['myElements']

    def to_string(self):
        return f"Vector with {self.length} elements"

    def next_element(self):
        for i in range(self.length):
            yield str(i), (self.mem + i).dereference()

    def children(self):
        return self.next_element()

    def display_hint(self):
        return "array"
```

Notice that the `next_element` method is actually a generator, since it uses `yield` instead of return.

However, when I tried to use this pretty printer each element was printed as just `Value: double,`. The problem is because of `FailPrinter`. The way you have registered the pretty printers means that except for the Vector class, **everything else** is printed using the `FailPrinter`, including each individual element. You don't really need (or want) a "Fail" printer.

Therefore, just use the class I have provided and register it with

```py
def lookup_type(val):
    if(str(val.type) == 'Vector'):
        return VectorPrinter(val)

gdb.pretty_printers.append(lookup_type)
```

---

Let's see this pretty printer in action. Consider the main.cpp file below

```cpp
class Vector {
public:
    double* myElements;
    unsigned int length;

public:
    Vector(unsigned int length) : length(length) {
        myElements = new double[length];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            myElements[i] = i;
        }
    }

    ~Vector() {
        delete[] myElements;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Vector v(10);
    return 0;
}
```

If we print `v` in gdb we get

[image: pretty printting vector v]

---

**Note**: If you are interested, I have created a few pretty printers for vector, matrix and cube classes in the [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library as well as for `std::complex`. These pretty printers are available [here](https://github.com/darcamo/gdb_armadillo_helpers). Looking at the code might help you creating other pretty printers.

Comment: Thank you! This is a fantastic answer and works a treat. I didn't know about the "children" function and this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Do you really need `str(val.type)`? Why not use `val.type.tag` instead? (Otherwise, thanks for the answer, works like a charm!)

Comment: @MatthieuM. `val.type.tag` should work as well.